# I am using a third party library 'react-player' which has some methods

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<Props> = () => {
  //some code//

  const handleOnStart = () => {
     ....
  };

  return (
    <ReactPlayer  data-testid={`video-player-${media.id}`} ref={(player) => ref(player, index)} className={`${styles["react-player"]}`} width="100%" height="100%"
                            url={media.url}
                            controls={true}
                            pip={false}
                            playing={(function () { if (index === 0) { return true } else return false }())}
                            config={{
                                youtube: {
                                    playerVars: {
                                        showinfo: 1,
                                        disablekb: 0,
                                        enablejsapi: 1,
                                        modestbranding: 1,
                                        rel: 0,
                                        fs: 0,
                                        iv_load_policy: 3,
                                        playsinline: 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }}
                            playsinline={true}
                            onStart={() => handleOnStart(index)}
                            onPlay={() => handleOnStart(index)}
                            onPause={() => handleOnMediaPause()}
                            onEnded={() => handleOnMediaPause()}
                            onError={() => handleOnError()}
                        />
  );
};
```

I am new to testing.I am trying to test the play, pause functionaltiy of ReactPlayer of react-player package. How can I mock the 'ReactPlayer' component and can access events and instances with 'jest' and/or 'React test library'?

Comment: There are tests for this library in its [repo](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player/tree/master/test)

Comment: Thank you for replying @Art but i want to test it in my project. Also while debugging i found out that it internally usese iframe which is not getting rendered when i am checking it using screen.debug(). Any idea around that?

Comment: Sure, you should see iframe [option here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/reference/#context)

Comment: I did not get the answer here @Art. Thanks for the link btw.