# mocking 'react-player' default methods in tests

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-player

ReactPlayer comes with the default methods for onStart, onPlay, onEnd functions. While trying to write the tests, it is not covered which reduces the codecoverage.

Similar to: [I am using a third party library 'react-player' which has some methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71478390/i-am-using-a-third-party-library-react-player-which-has-some-methods)

am new to testing.I am trying to test the play, pause functionaltiy of ReactPlayer of react-player package. How can I mock the 'ReactPlayer' component and can access events and instances with 'jest' and/or 'React test library'?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question you reference, you pretty much copy pasted it. You shouldn't do that, you should upvote that question instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to unit test a library that has unit tests of it's own. You are talking about code coverage, so I suspect that you want to test your own code that uses the functions from React-Player.
Could you share that code? both the component and the test that you have written so far?

You probably want to mock the module with something like:

```
jest.mock(
  'react-player',
  () => {
     return {
       open: jest.fn(),
       onPlay: jest.fn(),
       onEnd: jest.fn()
     };
  },
);
```